# linking google calendar API with laravel to create calendars and events

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use Google's calendar API to create calendars and save them into my google calendar directly through my app, I would also like to create events but I cant seem to get this to work, there's no error whatsoever but still I don't see the calendar in my list.

```php
$client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("GOOGLE CALENDAR");
        $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        $client->setAuthConfig('pr-test-4ad4a00e3031.json');
        $client->setAccessType("offline");

        $service =  new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $calenders =  new \Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
        $calenders->setDescription('ramzi');
        $calenders->setSummary('test');
        $service->calendars->insert($calenders);
        print_r($calenders);
```

the JSON file has the credentials.

And this is the output I get when I print the variable `$calenders`

```php
Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar Object
(
    [conferencePropertiesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceProperties
    [conferencePropertiesDataType:protected] => 
    [description] => ramzi
    [etag] => 
    [id] => 
    [kind] => 
    [location] => 
    [summary] => test
    [timeZone] => 
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Start by checking what the `insert` method call actually returned …?

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to achieve what you are trying to do(Create new calendars and events in them):

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

function getClient(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Calendar API PHP');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


function createCalendar($service){
    $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
    $calendar->setSummary('calendarSummary');
    $calendar->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
    try {
        $createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);
        echo $createdCalendar->getId();
        return $createdCalendar->getId();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        printf('An error occured creating the Calendar ' . $e->getMessage());
        return null;
    }    
}

function insertMyevents($service, $calendarId){
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => 'Google I/O 2019',
        'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
        'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
        'start' => array(
          'dateTime' => '2019-11-13T09:00:00-07:00',
          'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ),
        'end' => array(
          'dateTime' => '2019-11-14T17:00:00-07:00',
          'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        )
    ));
    try{
        $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        printf('An error occured inserting the Events ' . $e->getMessage());
    }   
}

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
// Creeate new calendar
$calendarId = createCalendar($service);
// Insert events into new Calendar if it was created succesfully
if($calendarId){
    insertMyevents($service, $calendarId);
}
```

You were creating the ***$client*** in the wrong way without setting all the previous steps as it is said in the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php). I also recommend you to check the next links, which bring some examples on how to use the Calendar API for PHP and the docs from all the methods you could use:

- [Calendars: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [Calendar API - PHP](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/index.html)